# Как отобразить список файлов корневой папки через google drive api android?

Tags: android, google-api

Доброе время суток. Я хотел бы создать приложение для просмотра всех файлов в google drive, которые лежат в корневой папке. Проблема заключается в том, что я могу установить права только для создания и просмотра файлов или папок созданными приложением.

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

Но мне нужно просматривать файлы, которые я закинул на гугл драйв с браузера (насколько я понимаю, что проблема в раздаче прав доступа, но нигде так и не смог это найти).